# php return function string

Tags: php, wordpress

First of all I am sorry for my English

I have problem with returning (string) of function result in Wordpress.

Here is my PHP code.

```
<?php

function printItem($item){
          $r = '<td><a href="#" class="tooltips" title="';
          $r.= "Nazwa kanału: <b>". $item->nazwa_kanalu."</b><br>\n";
          $r.= "Język: <b>".$item->jezyk."</b><br>\n";
          $r.= "Napisy: <b>".$item->napisy."</b><br>";
          $r.= "Dzwięk: <b>".$item->dzwiek."</b><br>";
          $r.= "Obraz: <b>".$item->obraz."</b><br>";
          $r.= "Rodziaj: <b>".$item->rodzaj."</b><br>";
          $r.= "Dostępny w: <b>".$item->pakiety."</b><br>";
          $r.= '"><img src="'.$item->field_logo_fid.'"></a></td>';

    return $r;
}

function printJambox($pakiet,$row=7){
        $r = '<table>'."\n";
        foreach( JamboxChannelsByRows($pakiet,$row) as $v ){
                $r.= "<tr>\n";
                foreach ($v as $item){
                       $r.= printItem($item);
                }
                for ($i=0;$i<($row-sizeof($v));$i++){
                        $r.= "<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
                }
                $r.= "</tr>\n";
        }
        $r.= "</table>\n";
    return $r;
}


function JamboxChannelsByRows($pakiet,$row=7)
{       
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.jambox.pl/xml/listakanalow.xml');
        $result = Array();
        $rowArray = Array();
        foreach($xml -> node as $item)
        {       echo $item;
                if( strstr($item->pakiety,$pakiet))
                {
                        if (sizeof($rowArray) < $row){
                                $rowArray[] = $item;
                        }
                        if (sizeof($rowArray) == $row){
                                $result[] = $rowArray;
                                $rowArray = Array();
                        }
                }
        }
        if ( sizeof($rowArray) != 0 ){
                $result[] = $rowArray;
        }
        return $result;
}

//[foobar]
function jambox_func( $atts ){
    return printJambox($atts['pakiet'],$atts['row']);

}
add_shortcode( 'jambox', 'jambox_func' );

?>
```

When I only **return printJambox($atts['pakiet'],$atts['row']);**
My result is like this (the problem is with  tag).

```
Nazwa kanału: <b>TV6</b><br />Język: <b>polski</b><br />Napisy: <b></b><br />Dzwięk: <b>Stereo</b><br />Obraz: <b>SD 16:9</b><br />Rodziaj: <b>rozrywka</b><br />Dostępny w: <b>Start HD, Mikro HD, Mini HD, Wielotematyczny HD, Wielotematyczny Super HD, Wielotematyczny Mega HD</b><br />„>

<img src=" https:="" www.jambox.pl="" sites="" default="" files="" tvlogo="" tv6.png"="">
```

But when I change the return to echo I have

```
<img src="https://www.jambox.pl/sites/default/files/tvlogo/tv6hd.png">
```

And the result is always displayed on the top of my website.

Please is there anyone who can explain what is going on?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you call printJambox too please?

Comment: I call it in here:function jambox_func( $atts ){
    return printJambox($atts['pakiet'],$atts['row']);}

Comment: It sounds like when its being returned it is being processed by a filter or something. Do you have any sort of filter on `the_content`?

Comment: No there is no filter.